# How to pass values into anonymous function that is triggered by an event?

Tags: javascript, function, events, kineticjs

I have he following code in Kinetic.js:

```
    function pacmanMove(x, y , duration, bate, color) {
        var tween = new Kinetic.Tween({
            node: group,
            duration: duration,
            x: x,
            y: y,
            onFinish: function() {
                changeColor(color);
                window[bate].remove();
            }
        });
        return tween;
    }

    var eat = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < linkItemsLen; i++) {
        eat.push(pacmanMove(linkItems[i][2], 65, 1, linkItems[i][0], linkItems[i][4]));
        window[linkItems[i][0]].on('mouseover', function() {
            this.tween = eat[i];
            this.tween.play();
        });
    }
```

I'm trying to pass a tween that is created on the fly into a mouseover event, but the tween is always undefined, so when the event is triggered I get an error message `TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'this.tween.play')` why? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using ***closure*** to capture the current `i` and use `var` instead to create private variables.

```
for(var i = 0; i < linkItemsLen; i++) {
        eat.push(pacmanMove(linkItems[i][2], 65, 1, linkItems[i][0], linkItems[i][4]));
        window[linkItems[i][0]].on('mouseover', (function(index) { //create closure to capture current index.
           return function(){
              //Use var instead
              var tween = eat[index];
              tween.play();
            }
        })(i));
    }
```

Because you're attaching event handlers in loop, at the end of the loop, the `i` is equal to `linkItemsLen` which outside of your `eat` array => `eat[i]` returns `undefined`. All your event handlers lose the current `i`.

Using the same technique, you could also pass the tween directly to the function:

```
for(var i = 0; i < linkItemsLen; i++) {
            eat.push(pacmanMove(linkItems[i][2], 65, 1, linkItems[i][0], linkItems[i][4]));
            window[linkItems[i][0]].on('mouseover', (function(tween) { //create closure to capture current eat[i].
               return function(){
                  tween.play();
                }
            })(eat[i]));//Pass the current eat[i]
        }
```